# How to tell python to wait for shell (.sh) script

Tags: python, sh, wait, os.system

I am calling a shell (.sh) script from my python code and I want to tell Python to wait for the script to end before continuing to the rest of the code. For the record, the script is calling a HPC cluster some calculations which take approximately 40-50min. I could probably do `sleep()` and force python to wait for these 40-50min, but firstly I do not always know the amount of time that should wait, and secondly I was hoping for a more efficient way of doing this.
So, the script is called by using `os.system("bsub < test.sh")`.

Is there any way to actually tell python wait until the script is finished and then continue with the rest of the code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `os.system()` already waits for the command to exit.  Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: I think the problem here is that `bsub` is used for submitting batch jobs. The job runs asynchronously, `bsub` doesn't wait for it to finish.

Comment: Don't use `bsub`, just run the script itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think **@Barmar** identifies the problem in a few comments

When you run `bsub`, it submits the job and immediately returns, rather than waiting for completion.

You should either

- add the `-K` arg to bsub for it to wait [ref](https://superuser.com/questions/46312/wait-for-one-or-all-lsf-jobs-to-complete)
- skip `bsub` and run the script directly
- write some independent marker at the end of your script (perhaps a file) and have the Python script check for it in a loop (maybe every 1-5s so it doesn't flood that resource)
- re-write the script in pure Python and directly incorporate it into your logic